# mutex lock in Nant

Tags: com, nant, mutex

How do I implement Mutex lock in Nant?  The reason why I need this feature is because I register COM components in order to get my build working.  Then at the end of the build 
I un-register the COM components.

Without mutex lock, different version of COM are registered and face some issues.

So, it would be better if we apply Mutex lock in Nant script.  That way if the build is running other project will wait until it finishes.

Comment: Your question might be better expressed as "how do I prevent multiple NAnt scripts from running at the same time on the same machine?".

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of doing this is to create your own task that would allow you to lock on a global mutex, and then another task to unlock it.  These new tasks can either be build separately and added to NAnt by copying dlls into NAnt\bin folder, or by extending NAnt directly from your build files

The information to get you started is found on [<script/> Task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/script.html)